# In Android, where does the file downloaded from Firebase storage get stored?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded a file to Firebase Storage from my project console. Now, I downloaded that file from my app using the method '*Download to a local file*' as mentioned in the Firebase Storage documentation, but I am not able to find the downloaded file on my phone.

Can someone tell me where does that file get downloaded to?

```
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://ldq-app-d2e6b.appspot.com");

    button_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String fileName = new String(editText_file.getText().toString());

            StorageReference childReference = storageReference.child("Quizzes");

            StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child("Quizzes/" + fileName + ".pdf");

            File localFile = null;

            try {
                localFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, "pdf");
            }
            catch (IOException ioe){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            fileReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"File downloaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Download failed. Try again!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Button working",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @rahulkapoor Added the code

Comment: You are creating temp file, see my code and don't forgot to add WritePermission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Firebase Document, they are creating a temporary file for saving Image from Url. [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

```
File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
```

If you want to store it on phone's internal memory or in external memory then just create a File with storage path and pass it to **FileDownloadTask**.

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "directory_name");
// Create direcorty if not exists
if(!storagePath.exists()) {
    storagePath.mkdirs();
}

final File myFile = new File(storagePath,"file_name");

yourStorageRef.getFile(myFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    // Local temp file has been created
}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
}
});
```

Comment: Using the above code, the app will create a directory, if it does not exist, and then store the downloaded file into that directory. Right?

Comment: Yes first create directory then add file into it by using, final File myFile = new File(storagePath,"file_name");

Comment: Not able to download now. I have edited the code in the question to reflect my latest code. Can you take a look please?

Comment: Don't update your original question, add in comments or in new section.

Comment: You are getting successful download message? Did directory created?

Comment: No. Download failed message and directory not created

Comment: In the log, I get a message that there is an exception as the directory does not exist.

Comment: Can you print filename.

Comment: also print complete exception

Comment: where do I see the file downloaded from firebase on my phone. I got this on my LogCat `/storage/emulated/0/BCMApp/Img1494533768342.jpg` but I can't see any file with that name or the directory in my Phone's gallery or the Internal Storage. Can you please help.
Where does the downloaded file get stored ?

Comment: Did you received successful listener

Comment: How about in Android Q, how to put it in default folder like Pictures, DCIM, Musics, Movies?