# how to retrieve pdf file firebase once?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, offlineapps

i am using **Firebase** storage to store my *PDF* book after i use the download link from Firebase storage to load it in my *PDFView* using byte[] array
    it's works fine but i want to load it only first time after that user will browse it offline please help me where to add Firebase offline 
i need to retrieve that book only once so the user will need internet only first time
also i saw documentation  where to put this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

this is my activity .java it works fine put i have wait to retrieve my book every time please help me

```
package com.xxxx.xxxxx;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 PDFView pdf;
 String url;
 DatabaseReference mData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
        pdf=findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
url="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/programminglib-978cc.appspot.com/o/JavaScriptEnlightenment-arabic-17.01-itwadi.com.pdf?alt=media&token=aa160de7-8cfa-4ec1-813f-0d67e2d8f307";
        new RetrievePDFbyte()
                .execute(url);



    }

class RetrievePDFbyte extends AsyncTask<String,Void,byte[]>{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("getting the book content...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected byte [] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try{
            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
                inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
        pdf.fromBytes(bytes).load();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: create file from inputStream and save locally,

Comment: pls  try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256500/in-android-where-does-the-file-downloaded-from-firebase-storage-get-stored

Comment: Using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` enabled disk persistence in the Firebase **Realtime Database**, a database for synchronize JSON data. It has nothing to do with Firebase **Storage**, which you use for storing and accessing files.

Comment: if i store the url in firebase database then load the url ? it's effecient ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to download your `.pdf` file and store it locally on user device. This means that user will be able to read the file even if no internet connection is present, because the user will be able to open the file from its device. According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files), you can achieve this, using the following code:

```
islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg");

File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");

islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

But rememeber, every time you open the application check for the existens of the file and download it only if the file does not exist.

Comment: still don't understand how t achieve that plz help

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: you just paste the code from Firebase documentation plz explain me where to put the code and what i need more ?

Comment: Yes, I just copied and paste here. It is a straightforward example. You need to add this code inside your `onCreate` method where you are actually need it. There is no need for something more.

Comment: bro i am confused i used many functions to download the file but all the methods goes to set the url link manualy

Answer (score 0):

in place of byte [] replace with Boolean

```html
 protected byte [] doInBackground(String... strings)
 
 replacing 
 
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
```